# optimal regularity for elliptic pdes with $div(L^\infty)$ right-hand side (Hodge decomposition?)

Tags: reference-request, harmonic-analysis, elliptic-pde, regularity

> **Question**: In a smooth, bounded domain $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^d$, is it true
> that solutions $\phi_f$ of
> $$ \begin{cases}
>  -\Delta \phi_f=\operatorname{div}f & \mbox{in }\Omega\\ \phi_f = 0 & \mbox{on }\partial \Omega \end{cases} $$ satisfy $$
> \|\nabla\phi_f\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)} \leq C \|f\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)} $$
> when **$f\in C^1_c(\Omega)$ is $C^1$ with compact support**?

Of course this smells like a borderline false statement, since $L^\infty$ elliptic regularity usually fails (for example it is well known that $\Delta\phi\in L^\infty$ does not imply $\phi\in W^{2,\infty}$, let alone with quantified estimates).
However, note here that 1) the right-hand side is in divergence form, 2) I am imposing continuity and compact support of the r.h.s., and 3) I am not interested in the seconde-order derivatives. In fact what I really need is that the normal derivative $\|\partial_n\phi_f\|_{L^\infty(\partial\Omega)}$ can be controlled by $\|f\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}$, if that helps (although I don't think this should make any difference)

I am not even convinced that the result is either true or blatantly false, but I have somehow the feeling that this should be related to fine properties of the Hodge decomposition, since $\nabla\phi_f$ is of course the gradient part in the decomposition $f=\nabla\phi_f + f_0$ of a vector field $f$ into a gradient $\nabla\phi_f$ and a solenoidal field $\operatorname{div}f_0=0$.

Also, maybe potential theory could help, but my expertise here is extremely limited, so any help, pointer, or reference would be most welcome!

---

**Addendum:** I would actually be interested in nonsmooth domains. Of course mere Lipschitz regularity is too much to hope for, since there are counterexamples $\Omega$ such that $\Delta\phi\in C^{\infty}(\bar\Omega)$ with $\phi$ failing to be even in $W^{1,p}$ for some $p$. But perhaps if $\Omega$ is "not too nasty", for example locally $C^{1,1}$ with finitely many corners, or whatever? In any case, even the case of smooth domains is itneresting I believe, so I'll start a bounty.

Comment: A colleague of mine made the clever observation that $f\in L^\infty$ meanse $div f\in W^{-1,\infty}$, and I'm looking for $\nabla\phi\in L^\infty\Leftrightarrow \phi\in W^{1,\infty}$. So, contrarily to what I was thinking, I am indeed trying at least formally to "gain two derivatives" from $W^{-1,\infty}$ to $W^{-1+2,\infty}=W^{1,\infty}$. Thus I am indeed hoping for an elliptic regularity with $p=\infty$ and therefore I guess I am doomed... I haven't tried yet to construct a counterexample, but now this should not be too hard a task.